# How to aggregate string by specific ID - (String1 - a)(String1 - b)(String2 - a)(String2 - b)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I need to be able to aggregate strings and the values of another cell based on the string value and its identifier value.

I have tried a couple of ways of summing the values, and filtering by specific items, and have tried to then sum based off of the contains text but there is no good way I've found.

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ A            ║ B               ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ Product Name ║ Product Quantity║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductA - 1 ║ 12              ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductA - 2 ║ 2               ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductB - 1 ║ 28              ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductB - 2 ║ 21              ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductC - 1 ║ 1               ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductC - 2 ║ 4               ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductD - 1 ║ 98              ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductD - 2 ║ 75              ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductE - 1 ║ 5               ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ ProductE - 2 ║ 9               ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

I am not sure how I would do it to sum(A) and sum(B) where A contains identical text excluding the identifier.

Currently, I am doing a query to get only A and B from the larger dataset and then doing a `Find and Replace` to remove all `- 1` and `- 2` and then doing

````
=QUERY(A:B,"Select A, sum(B) group by A order by sum(B) desc")```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+) - \d+")), B2:B}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by sum(Col2) desc
  label sum(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Can you explain the REGEXECTRACT?

Comment: sure. we regexextract everything `(.+)` before `-` followed by number `\d+`

Comment: Is there a way to add to this? I have another product sheet that is split with (50 Pack) and (25 Pack)? This would be very useful for it as well.

Comment: it would be: `"(.+) \d+ Pack"` asuming items are: `xxx 50 Pack`, `yyy 25 Pack`

Comment: it would be: `"(.+) \(\d+ Pack\)"` asuming items are: `xxx (50 Pack)`, `yyy (25 Pack)`